# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}K\left ( \sqrt{1-x^2} \right ) K\left ( \sqrt{1-x^4} \right )\text{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

How can we get a closed expression for this integral,
$$
\int_{0}^{1}K\left ( \sqrt{1-x^2}  \right )
K\left ( \sqrt{1-x^4}  \right )\text{d}x$$
where an complete elliptic integral $K(x)$ defined by $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1-x^2t^2}  }\text{d}t$ for $|x|<1$ appears and $x$ is the elliptic modulus?

- Observation 1: We can make a use of
  $$
  \int_{0}^{1}x^n K\left ( \sqrt{1-x^2}  \right )\text{d}x
  =\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{n+1}{2}  \right )^2 }{
  \Gamma\left ( \frac{n+2}{2}  \right )^2}.
  $$
  However, I don't know exactly the behaviour of function $K\left ( \sqrt{1-x^4}  \right)$ around $x=0$. Expanding him at other points seems to also be a messy calculation.
- Observation 2: We may notice,
  $$
  \int_{0}^{1}K\left ( \sqrt{1-x^2}  \right )
  K\left ( \sqrt{1-x^4}  \right )\text{d}x=2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K\left ( \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2} }  \right )
  K\left ( \sqrt{1-x^4}  \right )  }{
  \sqrt{1+x^2} }\text{d}x.
  $$

I am grateful for all your help.

Comment: $\sqrt{1-x^4} = \sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1+x^2}$. Since the second term appears in the other simplification you wrote, is there another elliptic function identity you can use to separate out a product like that?

Comment: The identity $$K(\sqrt{1-x^4}) = \frac{4K(x^2)}{\pi}\log\left(\frac{2}{x}\right) - 2\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}\right)x^{4} + \left(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{1}{1\cdot 2} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 4}\right)x^{8} + \cdots\right]$$ may help, but it involves a log term as well. Do you have an identity for $\int_0^1 (x^n\log x) K(\sqrt{1-x^2})\,dx$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you not differentiate the observation $1$ identity with respect to $n$?

Comment: @KStarGamer: this is a case of missing the obvious. I hope you can understand. And thanks for your response.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh haha it’s completely okay! I’m a big fan of your answers anyway- they’ve massively helped me learn elliptic function theory.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\int_{0}^{1}K\left ( \sqrt{1-x^2}  \right )
K\left ( \sqrt{1-x^4}  \right )\text{d}x
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4}{16}
 {}_4F_3\left ( \begin{array}{c|}
\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14\\
\frac12,\frac12,1
\end{array}\text{ }1 \right )-\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^4}{4}
 {}_4F_3\left ( \begin{array}{c|}
\frac34,\frac34,\frac34,\frac34\\
1,\frac32,\frac32
\end{array}\text{ }1 \right ).
$$

Comment: I suppose this is an answer in progress and we can get more details / steps very soon.